# How to redirect after resetting password in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a reset password functionality. I want to know how will i redirect the user to the login page after successfully resetting password. This is my code.

```
public function UpdatePassword(){

    $tok = $_SESSION['token'];
    $newpass = md5($this->security->xss_clean($this->input- 
>post('newpass')));
    $confpass = md5($this->security->xss_clean($this->input- 
>post('confpass')));



        if($newpass == $confpass){

            $this->db->where('password', $tok);
            $this->db->update('user', array('password' => 
$confpass));
            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            return true;

            }else{
            return false;
            }   

        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_submit', 
 'new and conf does not match');
            redirect(base_url('Login/resetpassword'));

        }

        //redirect(base_url('Login/Login'));    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add redirect function after password update code.

```
public function UpdatePassword(){

    $tok = $_SESSION['token'];
    $newpass = md5($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('newpass')));
    $confpass = md5($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('confpass')));

        if($newpass == $confpass){

            $this->db->where('password', $tok);
            $this->db->update('user', array('password' => $confpass));
            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            /*here you need to add redirect url if you want redirect on login page 
            example login page url is xyz.com/login then pass login in redirect function
            */
                redirect('login');
                exit;
            }else{
                 return false;
            }

        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_submit','new and conf does not match');
            redirect(base_url('Login/resetpassword'));

        }

        //redirect(base_url('Login/Login'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

redirect to logout page so user can login again with new password

```
public function UpdatePassword(){

$tok = $_SESSION['token'];
$newpass = md5($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('newpass')));
$confpass = md5($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('confpass')));

    if($newpass == $confpass){

        $this->db->where('password', $tok);
        $this->db->update('user', array('password' => $confpass));
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        /*here you need to add redirect url if you want redirect on login page 
        example login page url is xyz.com/login then pass login in redirect function
        */
            redirect('logout');
            exit;
        }else{
             return false;
        }

    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_submit','new and conf does not match');
        redirect(base_url('Login/resetpassword'));

    }

    //redirect(base_url('Login/Login'));
}
```